# Seeking a better understanding of how this query works?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am a little confused about #7 of the "sum and count" section on [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT)

The question is :

> For each continent show the continent and number of countries with
>   populations of at least 10 million.

This answer worked, but I am not sure exactly how :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(continent), COUNT(name)
FROM world
WHERE name IN 
    ( SELECT name 
      FROM world 
      WHERE population > 10000000 ) 
GROUP BY continent
```

However, it is not making sense intuitively. I am not seeing how  it makes sense to have this subquery :

```
          SELECT name 
          FROM world 
          WHERE population > 10000000
```

Mainly because we are returning *all* the countries of 10,000,000+  population.. .however we want to link each continent to its own group of 10,000,000+ countries.

Does SQL automatically know to connect the `continent` with its own `countries`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The query is assuming that the `name` column is unique.

By the way, this is a bad query.  For instance, it suggests that `distinct` is a function.  A much better way to write this query is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT continent, sum(case when population >= 10000000 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent;
```

Note:

I realize that the first query will filter out Antartica, so this is an even better query:

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(*)
FROM world
WHERE population >= 10000000 
GROUP BY continent;
```

I have no idea why SQLZoo would have such a complex query for something that is pretty simple.

Comment: admittedly the `sum(case when population > 10000000 then 1 else 0 end)` is much more clever and neat :-) thanks

Comment: just one small remark for a complete answer. the exercise says "with populations of _at least_ 10 million", so `>=` seems to be the appropriate operator.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT is not a function, it works on the whole row/result set! (Adding redundant parenthesis around continent makes no difference.)

DISTINCT is also not needed here because you are already doing a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery selects `name` of all countries that have the required population. It's using that to filter the actual query, which selects `continent` from `world`, but only where `name` is `IN` the list returned from the subquery.